# How do I get past size limitations in converting and MDB File

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

My Palm Pilot application stopped working after installing Micosoft Updates, and will not work even after reinstalling. My data files have long ago been transformed into MDB files by the firm which inherited Palm Software. In order to try to save my data, I opened the file with Microsoft Excel. It read the whole file and imported it, but limited the size of some of the larger records in the file and truncated them, causing me to lose data. Any help in restoring my data would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried owning then in MS Access? Can you open them in a text editor,  eg notepad? What is the site of the files? What are big records? Have you

Comment: Thanks to all responders. Yes, a limitation of 256 bytes would seem reasonable and explain my situation. I appreciate all responses. I don't own access, but I can try notepad and then go to Open Office. And, yes, I certainly work with copies of the source file, but the source file is always recreatable since I have about four years of backups by Acronis.

Comment: MDB is a Microsoft Database File (MS Access Jet database I think), and so it is a binary file. You won't get much with notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Excel is probably truncating memo fields to 256 characters. You need to open the MDB with software that supports memo fields: Access or perhaps Open Office *Base* if you don't have Access.

Open Office is open source and free.

I would suggest, if you haven't already, to make a copy of the file in question and only work with the copy.

Comment: Base - the database program